# Save focus on expanded group in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, expandablelistview

I have ExpandableListview inside NavigationDrawer. When group is expanded I collapse the previous expanded group, but when group is collapsed expanded group loses the focus (position of ExpandableListview goes down). Here's the code:

```
@Override
public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, long l) {

    if (mListView.isGroupExpanded(i)) {
        mListView.collapseGroupWithAnimation(i);
    } else {

        mListView.expandGroupWithAnimation(i);
        if(i!=lastExpandedGroupPosition )
            mListView.collapseGroupWithAnimation(lastExpandedGroupPosition);

        lastExpandedGroupPosition = i;
    }

     return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function `setSelectedGroup(groupPosition)` with the `expandablelistview` object while expanding the list. This would set the focus for the group , who's view you had clicked! 
Happy coding :)